# Show only (Low Search) shortcuts from logged in user

Tags: low-search

I am new to Low search, and happy I got shortcuts working.
My site is a member site, with memberdata in  a channel (Profile-edit) I want to show only shortcuts to the user that creates them (when they were logged in). Is there a way to filter shortcuts so that users only see their own shortcuts?

(And my apologies if I missed this in the docs)
(edit: I mean shortcuts created in the frontend, not collections)

Comment: Search Collections (only used for the Keywords filter) are like Channels and are most likely created by admins only. So I don't really understand what you mean by *"show only search collections to the user that creates them"*. Maybe you mean *entries* that were created by members? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Low, for you reaction.

In the meantime I found a 'dirty' solution:

I created a channel (called shortcut), and a form on the result page. URL as hidden field, the title of the entree in the channel 'shortcut'.

Now I can call these entrees made by AUTHOR and link them to the result page.
For the ones interested, this my (simple) code.

On result page:

```
<!-- formfields shortcut           -->
{exp:channel:form channel="shortcut" return="zoek/opdrachten" entry_id="{segment_5}"}
    {if segment_4 == ""}  
    <div class="forms" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}">
    <input type="hidden" name="entry_date" id="entry_date" value="{entry_date}">   
    <input type="hidden" name="title" id="title" value="{segment_3}" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>CV</legend>
            <label>Bewaar deze selectie<span class="forms-desc">Geef een beschrijving van deze zoekopdracht</span>
                <div class="controls">
                {field:shortcut_beschrijving}
                </div><!-- end control -->
            </label>
        <div class="controls" >
            <input type="submit" value="Voeg toe">
            </div>  
        </fieldset><br>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:form}
<!-- /formfields shortcut           -->
```

On the shortcut list page

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="shortcut"
    author_id="CURRENT_USER"
    disable="categories|category-fields|member-data"
    dynamic="no"
}

    {if no_results}Je hebt geen zoekopdrachten opgeslagen{/if}
    <p>
    <a href="{site_url}index.php/zoek/resultaat/{title}/{count}">{count}</a>
    {shortcut_beschrijving}
    </p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Totally possible, but be careful of the character limit in the title field. You might want to use a custom text field instead.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, was not aware of limit.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, per-member shortcuts aren't possible with Low Search at the moment. They are global.